# c++ read a saved objects in file.dat

Tags: c++

how should I proceed so that the function read, get reads the file.dat, whenever the file start?
I writing an object to the file, and I need to read when the program starts.

Problem: whenever I boot up the program to read the data once saved already, I have segmentation fault problems

```
    void DataManip::DataManipWrite(DateAdress *writer) {

    ofstream ObjectWriter;
    ObjectWriter.open("dbaddress.dat", ios::binary);    
    ObjectWriter.write((char *)&writer, sizeof(writer));
    ObjectWriter.close();

}

void DataManip::DataManipRead(DateAdress *reader) {

    ifstream ObjectReader;
    ObjectReader.open("dbaddress.dat", ios::binary);    
    ObjectReader.read((char *)&reader, sizeof(reader));
    ObjectReader.close();

}
```

Comment: Do you have some specific problems you want to share with us?

Comment: Also note `sizeof(writer)` will always just yield the size of the pointer, not the size of the data it points to.

Answer (score 0):

First, your sizeof operators return the size of the pointer instead of the class. Second, the class itself has to be a POD if you want to simply dump the memory to a file and read it later. Third, you're writing the value of the pointer itself, not the class data.